# Update apps notifications when opening application

Tags: ios, iphone, delegates, push-notification

I am creating an IOS application that makes use of PUSH notifications. When I send a PN, I send data to my application. IF my app is not active, I can then click the notification in the notification center to update the data in the app. However, IF I do not click the notification and I just resume the app via the launch screen, the app does not update correctly. Is there a way to update the apps pending notifications even if I don't press the notification center button and I just resume the app from the launch icon?

I have been scouring the internet with no luck. I have also tried to put the notification in a NSMUtable Array in the application delegate with no luck.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without you having a list of notifications that the app can download from the server you won't have a consistent solution so that is the best bet.

If you turned on background fetch for your notifications then the app could maintain a list of the received notifications, but this approach would fail for any notifications coming in after the user had force quit the app.

Comment: well that would actually be fine because the app would fetch the appropiate data anyway once the app restarts. Is there any reading material for background fetching?

Comment: do you have any reference for this? @Wain

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW57